# Keyboard setting wont open

Tags: keyboard, system-settings

I just updated my Ubuntu version from 14 to 16 and now all my custom keyboard short cuts didn't work any more. So I tried to manually add them, but when I go to **System Settings** and click on **Keyboard**, it won't open.

From the terminal it displays ,

```
john@john-PC:~$ unity-control-center keyboard 

(unity-control-center:4899): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard' does not contain a key named 'repeat'
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: Try open keyboard setting from terminal, open terminal, and run `unity-control-center keyboard`

Comment: @Liso. Updated question

Comment: Edit your [question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/857477/edit), and post output of following command : `apt-cache policy gnome-settings-daemon`